# Migrating from CouchbaseClientConfiguration to ClientConfiguration in the SDK

Tags: c#, couchbase

We’ve only just now come around to doing an upgrade from the (rather old) version of Couchbase we are on to the latest, for a variety of reasons. Unfortunately, we are currently using v1.1.6 of the Couchbase Client SDK for .NET. Moving to v2.3.4 seems to bring a lot of breaking changes, currently all centred around configuration.

We used to use the old `CouchbaseClientConfiguration` type, which seems to be been superseded now with `ClientConfiguration` (also with `BucketConfiguration` and `PoolConfiguration`). I’ve managed to migrate most of the configuration itself, but what is unclear now is the timeouts.

An example of how it used to hook up:

```
var clientConfiguration = new CouchbaseClientConfiguration()
    {
        Bucket = MembaseBucketName, 
        BucketPassword = MembaseBucketPassword
    };

foreach (string host in root.Elements("servers").Elements("add").Attributes("uri"))
{
    clientConfiguration.Servers.Add(new Uri(host));
}

// <servers retryCount="3" retryTimeout="00:00:30" >
clientConfiguration.RetryTimeout = TimeSpan.Parse(root.Element("servers").Attribute("retryTimeout").Value);
clientConfiguration.RetryCount = Convert.ToInt32(root.Element("servers").Attribute("retryCount").Value);

// <socketPool minPoolSize="10" maxPoolSize="10" connectionTimeout="00:00:30" deadTimeout="00:00:30" queueTimeout="00:00:30" receiveTimeout="00:00:30" />    
clientConfiguration.SocketPool.MinPoolSize =
    Convert.ToInt32(root.Element("socketPool").Attribute("minPoolSize").Value);
clientConfiguration.SocketPool.MaxPoolSize =
    Convert.ToInt32(root.Element("socketPool").Attribute("maxPoolSize").Value);
clientConfiguration.SocketPool.ConnectionTimeout =
    TimeSpan.Parse(root.Element("socketPool").Attribute("connectionTimeout").Value);
clientConfiguration.SocketPool.DeadTimeout =
    TimeSpan.Parse(root.Element("socketPool").Attribute("deadTimeout").Value);
clientConfiguration.SocketPool.QueueTimeout =
    TimeSpan.Parse(root.Element("socketPool").Attribute("queueTimeout").Value);
clientConfiguration.SocketPool.ReceiveTimeout =
    TimeSpan.Parse(root.Element("socketPool").Attribute("receiveTimeout").Value);
```

And this is what I've managed to translate so far:

```
var clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration
{
    BucketConfigs = new Dictionary<string, BucketConfiguration>
    {
        {
            MembaseBucketName,
            new BucketConfiguration
            {
                BucketName = MembaseBucketName,
                Password = MembaseBucketPassword,
                Servers = root.Elements("servers").Elements("add").Attributes("uri").ToList(_ => new Uri(_.Value)),
                PoolConfiguration = new PoolConfiguration
                {
                    MinSize = Convert.ToInt32(root.Element("socketPool").Attribute("minPoolSize").Value),
                    MaxSize = Convert.ToInt32(root.Element("socketPool").Attribute("maxPoolSize").Value),
                    ConnectTimeout = (int)TimeSpan.Parse(root.Element("socketPool").Attribute("connectionTimeout").Value).TotalMilliseconds,
                    WaitTimeout = (int)TimeSpan.Parse(root.Element("socketPool").Attribute("queueTimeout").Value).TotalMilliseconds,
                },
                DefaultOperationLifespan = (uint)TimeSpan.Parse(root.Element("socketPool").Attribute("receiveTimeout").Value).TotalMilliseconds,
            }
        },
    },
};
```

We used to specify: `QueueTimeout`, `DeadTimeout`, `ReceiveTimeout`, `ConnectionTimeout`, `RetryTimeout` and `RetryCount`. Where do these migrate to? I would assume they either have equivalent properties in the new code, or the concepts around them have changed.

Also, where do `Servers` and `PoolConfiguration` configurations live? They are both available on `ClientConfiguration` and `BucketConfiguration`. We only run one bucket, with a few server URIs, so the total config is not complicated.

Answer (score 2):

As best I can tell, I was quite close before. What I ended up with was this:

```
var clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration
{
    BucketConfigs = new Dictionary<string, BucketConfiguration>
    {
        {
            MembaseBucketName,
            new BucketConfiguration
            {
                BucketName = MembaseBucketName,
                Password = MembaseBucketPassword,
                Servers = root.Elements("servers").Elements("add").Attributes("uri").ToList(_ => new Uri(_.Value)),
                PoolConfiguration = new PoolConfiguration
                {
                    MinSize = Convert.ToInt32(root.Element("socketPool").Attribute("minPoolSize").Value),
                    MaxSize = Convert.ToInt32(root.Element("socketPool").Attribute("maxPoolSize").Value),
                    ConnectTimeout = (int)TimeSpan.Parse(root.Element("socketPool").Attribute("connectionTimeout").Value).TotalMilliseconds,
                    WaitTimeout = (int)TimeSpan.Parse(root.Element("socketPool").Attribute("queueTimeout").Value).TotalMilliseconds,
                    SendTimeout = (int)TimeSpan.Parse(root.Element("socketPool").Attribute("receiveTimeout").Value).TotalMilliseconds,
                },
                DefaultOperationLifespan = (uint)TimeSpan.Parse(root.Element("socketPool").Attribute("receiveTimeout").Value).TotalMilliseconds, // Belt and braces.
            }
        },
    },
    ViewRequestTimeout = (int)TimeSpan.Parse(root.Element("socketPool").Attribute("receiveTimeout").Value).TotalMilliseconds, // Belt and braces.
};
```

There appears to be no equivalent for `DeadTimeout` anymore, nor `RetryCount` and `RetryTimeout`, which in the [archived docs](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-sdk-net-1.3/#configuring-the-net-client-library) says are for:

> - `retryCount` The number of times to retry a failed attempt to read cluster config
> - `retryTimeout` (00:00:02) The amount of time to wait in between failed attempts to read cluster config

In the current docs, there is nothing similar to this that I can find.

`ReceiveTimeout` appears to have relevance on a few things, namely `PoolConfiguration.WaitTimeout`, `BucketConfiguration.DefaultOperationLifespan`, and `ClientConfiguration.ViewRequestTimeout`. I'm least confident about this as it's one configuration mapping to three new configuration options that seem to have similar behaviour.

The rest were pretty much a one-to-one.

Ignore the strange `(int)TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds` nonsense, it is a throwback to the current way in which we specify the configuration. It will need changing in future.

I will be revisiting this answer as I verify my assumptions based on the approach above. I still haven't figured out why the same configuration is in multiple levels - I would hope so you can default and then override values.